# How can I make the python logging library print logs in console while running Flask?

Tags: python, flask, logging

This is the configuration I have right now

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(
connection_string='InstrumentationKey='+app_insights_id)
)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def main_page():
    logger.debug('Hello Flask, on Azure App Service for Linux!')  <--- want this to be printed on console
    return 'Hello Flask, on Azure App Service for Linux!'
```

I am pretty sure this is possible since it was working for me until a couple of days back and after some change I cannot trace back, all logs stopped printing to console

I have tried setting the environment variable `FLASK_ENV` to `development`. That didn't work either.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984330/python-flask-print-to-console-and-log-file-simultaneously), we need to get logger from werkzeug, is there any way apart from this to get logs in console after starting flask?

Comment: Usually the logs will be printed according to the level. Can you try setting your logger level to `debug` or change your `logger.debug` to `logger.info`

Comment: @RitwikG as you can see in the code snippet I have set the level to `DEBUG`

Comment: Oops. Sorry I completely missed it.

Comment: I would guess that you somehow set up some logging earlier somewhere and `logging.basicConfig` becomes a no-op when there already is a logger defined.